# Reading CSV with encoded characters

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, decoding

I am working on a csv file with text data and for some reason some characters are not encoded in the usual format.

```
Add another song to the Cita RomГЎntica playlist. ,AddToPlaylist
add The Greyest of Blue Skies in Indie EspaГ±ol my playlist,AddToPlaylist
```

Thanks to a user from here, I managed to find it is related to cp1251 encoder.

```
text = 'Add another song to the Cita RomГЎntica playlist. ,AddToPlaylist'

converted = text.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```

prints the right text.

However when I want to do the following :

```
input_file = codecs.open("dataset_classif_chatbot.csv", "r",encoding='cp1251')
output_file = io.open("dataset_classif_chatbot_cleaned.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8')

def sanitize_characters(raw, clean):    
    for line in input_file:
        out = line.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
        output_file.write(out)
        
sanitize_characters(input_file, output_file)
```

I get the following error :

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-584a5d8034c1> in <module>
      8         output_file.write(out)
      9 
---> 10 sanitize_characters(input_file, output_file)

<ipython-input-3-584a5d8034c1> in sanitize_characters(raw, clean)
      4 def sanitize_characters(raw, clean):
      5     for line in input_file:
----> 6         out = line.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
      7         out=out.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
      8         output_file.write(out)

D:\Programmes\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py in encode(self, input, errors)
     10 
     11     def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
---> 12         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
     13 
     14     def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 46: character maps to <undefined>
```

Any idea ? I am very sorry I spent hours on this

Thank you,

Comment: If your file is encoded using `cp1251`, specify that you want to use this encoding when opening it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille as stated if I use encode cp1251 I get the second error unfortunately

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please always provide a [mre] and the corresponding, complete error traceback in your question. We never know exactly what you are doing and what code you run.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I edited it hopefully it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really related to CSV, but mainly to converting your file from one encoding (cp 1251) to another (utf-8).

Python distinguishes text (what you have in `str` objects) from their binary representation (what you have stored in files).

When you read a text file, the binary data gets decoded on-the-fly to text, according to the specified encoding (or the default, which depends on your system). When you write a text file, the text gets encoded.

In your function, you read text from a file where it is stored according to the cp 1251 encoding. What you get is just text.

In this line:

```
out=out.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```

you re-encode this text to a sequence of bytes, according to cp 1251, and try to decode this sequence as if it were some utf-8 encoded data, which of course fails.

You just have to read and write your data, specifying the correct encodings in `open` and let Python do the rest. So, to convert a cp 1251 encoded file into an utf-8 encoded one, just do:

```
 with open('test.txt', encoding='cp1251') as infile:
    with open('converted.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

If you want to open a cp 1251 file, manipulate the data, and store your output in utf-8, it would be something like:

```
 with open('test.txt', encoding='cp1251') as infile:
     # read from infile
     # and manipulate your data
 with open('converted.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
     # write to outfile
```

and nothing more.

Comment: Using your first proposal gave me the same error. 
out=out.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8') does work if out='... Cita RomГЎntica ...' so I don't really get your point. It just doesn't when looping over my whole csv.

Comment: OK. The assumptions in your question are wrong. It is unclear where the text at the start of your question comes from, but this is exactly what you get with a file encoded in utf-88 that you try to print/view as if it were cp1251. The file is utf8, remove all you introduced regarding cp1251 in your code, and just view it with a correct text editor or print it in a terminal that is aware of utf8.